# Azure search indexer not updating before 3 minute

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I was working with `azure-search` and able to map indexer with DB. Everything seems fine till here.

I want to update my indexer automatically/manually *every second* to keep `azure search` updated. Every time if data gets created/updated azure search indexer should get updated as soon as possible to give best user experience.

In [**DOC**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers) it's written that indexer can update every *5 minutes*.

> An indexer can re-index your table at most every five minutes. If your
>   data changes frequently, and the changes need to be reflected in the
>   index within seconds or single minutes, we recommend using the REST
>   API or .NET SDK to push updated rows directly.

I tried RESET API but it also has the limitation of *3 minutes*. This if following error I am getting when tried updating indexer frequently. Is this limitation is because of free search plan?

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "On-demand indexer invocation is permitted every 180 seconds for this service tier."
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this limitation is because of free search plan?

You could get the answer from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers) comment. Accroding to Eugenesh@MSFT metioned that it is the limit for free search plan.Paid tiers do not limit how frequently you can run an indexer.

> **paid tiers do not limit** how frequently you can run an indexer.

[image]

Comment: In addition, running an indexer on demand every second is not a good practice. If you want to update the search index in real time when adding documents to a Cosmos DB collection, you can insert those documents into both Cosmos DB and Azure Search at the same time, and avoid overhead of running indexer queries against your collection.

Comment: @EugeneShvets I was looking for drawbacks to a frequent indexer schedule and your comment points one out nicely: Frequent indexing could introduce latency to another competing resource that's also trying to use the data source. Thanks!